# Database structure for a list of items ( very different )

Tags: mysql, database, list, structure, normalization

I came to the following problem:
I have a list of users that can create lists
I have  tables that contains entities like:
 - movies - with different properties
 - pictures - with different properties
 - people profiles - with different properties
 - X type - with different properties ( a to do list).

A user can create a list ( where other users can add elements) with all the above types. ( for example a list with movies and actors and pictures galleries).

How can I store that list efficiently and without many problems :)

Thanks in advance

Comment: The different types are finite (e.g. only movies, pictures, people, todo)? Or is it infinite and users can define new types?

Comment: finite ( I will define manually all the types used in list)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you should create a separate table **Entity** that would be a base type for all your movies, pictures, etc. And a separate table **ListsItems** that would contain following columns: (`list_id`, `entity_id`), and table **UsersLists** of (`user_id`,  `list_id`).

**UsersLists** would contain users to lists mapping (every user may have many lists), **ListsItems** would contain lists to entities mapping (every list may have many entities), and **Entity** would contain entity type (movie, picture, whatever) and specific entity ID that would point to its native table (**Movie**, **Picture**, etc).

*Aufziehvogel* asked you about number of types because it's important for this entity type field resolving in a design. If you have a finite predefined number of types, you may make column `entity_type` an Enumeration, but if user should be able to create their own types, that's a more complicated problem and a table **SpecifiedEntity** should replace specific tables (**Movies**, **Pictures**, etc).

You may read something about normalization of relational databases to understand this issue in all the existing details.

Answer (score 0):

The solution you're looking for (and that Mkaz started describing) is a database pattern called Disjoint Subtypes.

I battled with the same problem a while ago, here's what I found:

[Object-oriented-like structures in relational databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600684/object-oriented-like-structures-in-relational-databases)

[Polymorphism in SQL database tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561576/polymorphism-in-sql-database-tables/561960)